# Python: copy file tree to a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a text file with a tree of all files / dirs from a place that I choose using `os.chdir()`. My approach is to print the tree and to save all prints to the text file. The problem is that it doesn't copy the printed tree and the file is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

And is there a way to write this kind of data to the file without to actually print it?

My code:

```py
import os
import sys

f = open("tree.txt", "w")
os.chdir("c:\\Users\Daniel\Desktop")
sys.stdout = f
os.system("tree /f")
f.close()
```

**Edit**

I was able to get the file tree from the clipboard after executing the command, however it gives me and eror when it tried to write to the txt file.

code:

```
import os
import tkinter

with open("tree.txt", "w") as f:
    os.system("tree /f |clip")
    root = tkinter.Tk()   
    tree = root.clipboard_get()
    print(tree)
    f.write(tree)
```

eror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Tick\code_test\files.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.write(tree)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode      
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 80: character maps to <undefined>
```

**solution**

So I found the problem, I needed to use codec to be able write unicode to the text file. Now it works very well

code:

```
import os
import tkinter
import codecs

with codecs.open("tree.txt", "w", "utf8") as f:
    os.chdir("c:\\Users")
    os.system("tree /f |clip")
    root = tkinter.Tk()   
    tree = root.clipboard_get()
    f.write(tree)
```

Comment: `sys.stdout` sets the output for the **current interpreter**. On the other hand, `os.system` **opens a new shell** so it is not affected by the `stdout` you set

Comment: So how come I can see the tree printed in the same console window of vsc?

Answer (score 0):

Method `check_output` from `subprocess` module can help you to catch program output:

```
import subprocess

f = open("tree.txt", "wb")   
tree_output = subprocess.check_output('tree /f', shell=True, cwd=r'c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop')
f.write(tree_output)
f.close()
```

Or with context manager:

```
import subprocess

with open("tree.txt", "wb") as f: 
    f.write(subprocess.check_output('tree /f', shell=True, cwd=r'c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop'))
```

Option `wb` is required because `check_output` returns bytes not a `str`. If you want to process output like a string - call `tree_output.decode()` first.

Comment: I'm quite close, the tree has been written in the txt file, but the formating is off. I'm gueesing there is a way to copy it properly because if I open cmd and run "tree /f |clip" and then manually paste it to a txt file the format of the tree stays the same as it was on the cmd window.
I thought about executing that command through the script and then paste it straight from the clipboard.